# Renaming a file - Google API direct download link

Tags: javascript, axios, google-api, download, puppeteer

I am using an external API to create and download a data extract. After the extract has been created, the API response includes a url. This url is a direct download link - I click it and a new browser tab opens, which automatically downloads the file to my downloads folder. I am trying to automate this process so I don't have to manually download and rename the file. Everything is working, except the file is always downloaded with a default name. We'll say this is "123456123456.csv.gz" to keep it ambiguous.

The link I follow is formatted like this-

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/(custom storage name)/(data extract id)/123456123456.csv.gz?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=(google service account credentials)&X-Goog-Date=(date)&X-Goog-Expires=(time until expiration)&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=(long string of number and letters)
```

I am currently using puppeteer to just open a new browser tab to that url, which downloads the file, and then close puppeteer-

```
async function downloadFile (url) {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
      {headless: false}
    );
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`${url}`);
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000); // just in case it takes a second
    await browser.close();
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I tried to directly edit the link with a custom file name like this-

```
...
  const autoFileName = '000000000000.csv.gz';
  const customFileName = `${date}-${reportingLevel}.csv.gz`;
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const newUrl = url.replace(autoFileName, customFileName);
    downloadFile(newUrl);
...
```

But when I open the new url in a browser, instead of downloading a file it gives me a page like this-

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Details>
<StringToSign>(sensitive information)</StringToSign>
<CanonicalRequest>GET (sensitive information) UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
</Error>
```

I can't find any documentation from google about these links - if anyone can find any I would love it!

At first I thought the '123456123456.csv.gz' section of the url was just the name to download the file as, but now I'm realizing the file is most likely stored in their google storage as '123456123456.csv.gz'.

Does anyone have ideas on how I can have this automatically rename my files so I don't have to do it manually? I did try using axios/fs to download instead, but had no luck even downloading the file, not to mention renaming it. I haven't used axios much before so it's possible I was doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like multiple problems here--does the download work without a rename? If not, then I'd worry about that rather than renaming. If the file does download, then renaming it should be totally agnostic of Puppeteer. A [mcve] will make it possible to help further. Ideally, pick some file that reproduces the behavior and can be shared publicly. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, the download does work. The rename does not. Sorry, I should have clarified that a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Puppeteer seems a little overkill, do you really need to involve a browser? Why not use axios, as you mentioned in your question's tags? Here is a basic working example:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const urls = ['https://placehold.co/400', 'https://placehold.co/600'];

(async () => {
  for (const url of urls) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });

    const originalFilename = url.split('/').pop();
    const dest = `foo-${originalFilename}.svg`;
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(dest);

    data.pipe(writer);
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      writer.on('finish', resolve);
      writer.on('error', reject);
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: This runs with no errors, but no file is downloaded... Not sure why.

Comment: Even when you run it as-is? It should download 2 svg files. If it works as-is, but not when you adapt the code for your usecase, could you provide a minimal version of your adapted code?

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong, I got it now! Thank you for the example. I'll post what I ended up with, it's too long for this comment.

Comment: I call this for each url-
await downloadAndRenameFile(downloadUrl, customFileName, filePath);

async function downloadAndRenameFile(url, fileName, filePath) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'stream' });
    const fullPath = path.join(filePath, fileName);
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(fullPath);
    response.data.pipe(writer);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      writer.on('finish', resolve);
      writer.on('error', reject);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading file:', error);
  }
}

Comment: Oh you're right, [`.pipe()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepipedestination-options) does not return a Promise, so you need to listen to the `finish` and `error` events. Glad you found a solution